# Parsing nested JSON information in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

From the JSON string below I'm trying to pull just all the waiverId's:

```
data = 
{
  "version": 4,
  "id": "(requestId)",
  "ts": "2022-11-14T20:24:50+00:00",
  "type": "checkins",
  "checkins": {
    "fromDts": "2022-07-01",
    "toDts": "2022-07-02",
    "moreCheckins": true,
    "checkins": [
      {
        "date": "2022-07-01 15:18:09",
        "waiverId": "(id1)",
        "position": 0,
        "firstName": "(first name)",
        "lastName": "(last name)"
      },
      {
        "date": "2022-07-01 15:19:10",
        "waiverId": "(id2)",
        "position": 0,
        "firstName": "(first name)",
        "lastName": "(last name)"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
for checkins in data['checkins']:
    print(checkins)
```

Which just gives:

```
fromDts
toDts
moreCheckins
checkins
```

I would like just a list of:
id1
id2

Answer (score 0):

You want to pull the list of `checkins` from `'checkins'` as in:

```py
for checkins in data['checkins']['checkins']:
    print(checkins)
```

The first key `checkins` returns a `dict` value containing a key of `checkins` that contains a list of the data you want in `dict` format.

Comment: Thank you! Much easier than I was making it out to be. Still very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

##### Assumptions:

1. The dictionary you deal with is already in the form that can be processed by python (so 'true' becomes 'True').
2. `response.json()` for this answer is not necessary, you should better specify what you want to do. I will treat the given variable directly as the dictionary in the correct form.

---

Simply iterate through the dataframe as indicated by [@user99999](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20070120/user99999) and add the elements you are looking for to the list:

```py
data = {
  "version": 4,
  "id": "(requestId)",
  "ts": "2022-11-14T20:24:50+00:00",
  "type": "checkins",
  "checkins": {
    "fromDts": "2022-07-01",
    "toDts": "2022-07-02",
    "moreCheckins": True,
    "checkins": [
      {
        "date": "2022-07-01 15:18:09",
        "waiverId": "(id1)",
        "position": 0,
        "firstName": "(first name)",
        "lastName": "(last name)"
      },
      {
        "date": "2022-07-01 15:19:10",
        "waiverId": "(id2)",
        "position": 0,
        "firstName": "(first name)",
        "lastName": "(last name)"
      }
    ]
  }
}

waiverIds = []
for checkins in data['checkins']['checkins']:
    waiverIds.append(checkins['waiverId'])

print(waiverIds)
```

Output will be:

```
['(id1)', '(id2)']
```